# Solving the "Transport" PDE in the sense of distributions with Dirac Delta Source

Tags: distribution-theory, linear-pde, partial-differential-equations, transport-equation

Let $\delta_0$ be the standard Dirac Delta distribution. I wish to solve the PDE $$u_t+cu_x=\delta_0$$ in the sense of distributions with initial condition $u(x,0)=g(x)$ for some continuous $g$. That is, I wish to find $u(x,t)$ such that
$$-\iint_\mathbb{R} u(x,t)(\phi_t+c\phi_x)dA=\phi(0,0)$$
where $\phi$ is any so-called test function.

Can anyone point in me the right direction? I tried to take a Fourier transform but that didn't seem to do much.

Edit:

To respond to a comment, taking the Fourier transform yields:
$$\mathcal{F}(u)_t+cik\mathcal{F}(u)=1$$
This is equivalent to the ODE $$f'(t)+cikf(t)=1$$
This ODE is solved by
$$\mathcal{F}(u)=f(t)=C e^{-(i kc t)} - i/(kc)$$
I'm unsure of where to go from here, or if this is correct.

Comment: What did you get upon taking the fourier transform? That should lead you the correct way

Comment: I agree that the Fourier transform *should* lead to the right answer, but there are some alternatives. Have you tried using Duhamel's principle? The delta function is likely easier to deal with as an initial condition since the action of the PDE is just to translate it.

Comment: So in taking the fourier transform you've suppressed the $\xi$ variable, which may have created confusion. In particular, your constant, $C$ is actually of the form $e^{k(\xi)}$ for some function of $k(\xi)$ (no $t$ dependence). Use the initial condition of $f(0, \xi) = \hat{g(\xi)}$ to determine $k(\xi)$ in terms of $g(\xi)$. Note: you'll need some stronger requirements than just continuity to make sense of the fourier transform of $g$.

Comment: I find that $C=\mathcal{F}(g)+i/k$, which isn't in the form you suggested. Could you elaboate?

Comment: @EditPiAf it is, i miscopied the problem (this doesn't really make a difference as far as I'm aware). This is really the 2D dirac distribution

Comment: @zz20s Do you think your statement $f′(t)+cikf(t)=1$ is correct? ie, taking the time derivative of a space Fourier Transform of a distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The r.h.s. of the partially Fourier-transformed equation in OP is incorrect. Indeed, spatial Fourier transformation of the 2D Dirac $\delta_0 =\delta(x)\delta(t)$ gives $\delta(t)$, not $1$. Moreover, the weak form in OP is incorrect too. Integrating by parts, we have
\begin{aligned}
0 &= \iint_{\Bbb R\times\Bbb R_+} (u_t + cu_x-\delta_0)\phi\,\text d x\,\text d t \\
&= -\int_{\Bbb R} g\phi|_{t=0}\, \text d x - \iint_{\Bbb R\times\Bbb R_+} u(\phi_t + c\phi_x)\,\text d x\,\text d t - \phi(0,0)
\end{aligned}
for any test function $\phi$.

The present problem amounts to the computation of the Green's function for the non-homogeneous advection equation $u_t+cu_x=f$. Fourier transformation in space and time of the PDE yields
$$
\text i(\omega-kc)\, \mathcal{F}_t\mathcal{F}_x u = 1
$$
where $\mathcal{F}_t = \int\text dt\, e^{-\text i\omega t}$ and $\mathcal{F}_x = \int\text dx\, e^{\text ik x}$. Thus, the solution is represented as
\begin{aligned}
u(x,t) &= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\iint \frac{e^{\text i(\omega t-kx)}}{\text i (\omega-kc)}\text dk\,\text d\omega \\
&= \frac{\text{sgn}(t)}2 \left( \frac{1}{2\pi} \int e^{-\text i k(x-ct)}\text dk \right) \\
&= \tfrac12 \text{sgn}(t)\, \delta(x-ct)
\end{aligned}
where the residue theorem was used (singularity at $\omega=kc$ -- see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4220282/418542)). Using the superposition principle, the solution to the initial problem may be expressed as
$$
u(x,t) = g(x-ct)+\tfrac12 \text{sgn}(t) \, \delta(x-ct) \, .
$$
As pointed out in the comments, an alternative consists in using Duhamel's principle, cf. [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhamel%27s_principle).

Comment: For the problem of interest, where the solution is to be understood in the sense of distribution, would it be possible to take the Fourier Transform in time only (ie $u\to \mathcal{F}_t u=\hat{u}(x,\omega)$)  and then differentiate the resulting Fourier Transform $\hat{u}(x,\omega)$ in $x$?

Comment: @zz20s I might have omitted the causality condition $t>0$ (it's not obvious how it should be included in the above computation), see answer by Qmechanic

Comment: "some care should be taken [...] weak sense": do you know a good reference on this topic in the context of Fourier Transforms?

Comment: @pluton I don't have any reference in mind for PDE and tempered distributions, but [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3332014/418542) could help

Comment: yes, the book you recommended in that post says (chapter 10) that "The spatial Fourier transform of a time derivative equals the time derivative of the Fourier transform." However, this is not clear when this statement fails... even in the framework of distributions.

Comment: There is the still pending question even though "my" answer (Edit June 2, 2020) seems to be correct: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3691147

Answer (score 2):

OP's first-order initial value problem (IVP) is

$$ \frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}+ c\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}~=~\delta(t)\delta(x), \qquad u(x,t\!=\!0)~=~g(x).\tag{1}$$

One idea is to transform the IVP (1) into the form

$$ \frac{\partial v(x^{\prime},t^{\prime})}{\partial t^{\prime}}~=~\delta(t^{\prime})\delta(x^{\prime}), \qquad v(x^{\prime},t^{\prime}\!=\!0)~=~g(x^{\prime}),\tag{2}$$

by make a suitable linear coordinate transformation $(x,t)\mapsto (x^{\prime},t^{\prime})$. A bit of thought using the chain rule reveals that the coordinate transformation
$$ x~=~x^{\prime}+ct^{\prime}, \qquad t~=~t^{\prime}, \tag{3}$$
will do the job.
The unique solution to the IVP (2) is evidently
$$ v(x^{\prime},t^{\prime})~=~\frac{1}{2}{\rm sgn}(t^{\prime})\delta(x^{\prime})+ g(x^{\prime}). \tag{4}$$ 
Hence the unique solution to the original IVP (1) is
$$ u(x,t)~=~\frac{1}{2}{\rm sgn}(t)\delta(x\!-\!ct)+ g(x\!-\!ct). \tag{5}$$